# Software to track change history (IT tech support)

Tags: task-management

I work at a new startup in India as tech support. We want to keep track of changes that we make to various servers we administer. For example: we deploy something, we change something in database etc.
Something distributed like google docs would work. GitHub is a nice idea but we want it to be private. But GitLab in our company is only used for coding purposes and we don't have access to that.
Currently, my idea is google docs, but is there something as good as it? It should not be self-hosted, instead be distributed.Good thing is we have that scrum thing and Atlassian confluence thing. Is there a way to do this stuff in that privately? (just within our dept)